# C# Unit-test not running when constructor class exist

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

This is a simple unit Test class with test method called 'TestMethod1()' . when i write ctor  inside it, unit test doesn't run anymore. but without ctor test case work as well.

```cs
public class OrderTests 
{
    public OrderTests (int value)
    {  }
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       Xunit.Assert.Equal(7, 7);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, what value do you expect the test runner (that needs to instantiate `OrderTests`) to pass to your `value` ctor parameter?

Comment: `int value` doesnt appear to be being used, so just remove it

Comment: I assume from OPs text, that OP already knows he/she *can* remove the ctorm but wonders why doing so has any effect on the test running successfully or not.

Comment: Is this the real code you show us? With xunit you have to write [Fact] attribute to make a method testmethod. https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/visual-studio

Comment: not actually i made simple class for ask my question, the real code for my project is unit test class that extend base class. so in the ctor is necessary for initialize baseclass.

Comment: how should your testrunner provide the args for the ctor? I suppose that's the issue here. The runner just looks for a parameterless ctor, if it doesn't find any, it can*t run the tests.

Comment: Look at [Prefer helper methods to setup and teardown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#prefer-helper-methods-to-setup-and-teardown)

Comment: parameterized ctor is not necessary to initialize base class. you can set whatever values you want from derive class ctor to base class. just remove the ctor parameter

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Actually, that link points out "xUnit has removed both SetUp and TearDown as of version 2.x". In fact, [xUnit's website has a comparison table](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons) where using a ctor/ `Dispose` method are the recommended way to implement SetUp/TearDown code in xUnit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `Fact` attribute to the test so that is recognised as a test and not just a method e.g.:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   Xunit.Assert.Equal(7, 7);
}
```

Comment: While that's true, the question makes it seem like the missing `[Fact]` attribute is not the issue in the actual code (where the test runs depending on whether or not there is a constructor explicitly defined for the test class). Presumably, the `[Fact]` attribute is only missing in the minimal sample shown in the question.

Comment: There weren't a lot of details so I tried to read between the lines - maybe incorrectly.